# glm function not taking correct dataset

Tags: r, glm

I have just started learning R and working on dataset which has 1470 cases. Name of dataset is ABC. Using as.factor, I have converted categorical variables as factors.

```
Dept_1 <- as.factor(ABC$Dept)
Education_1 <- as.factor(ABC$Education)
BusinessTravel_1 <- as.factor(ABC$BusinessTravel)
```

After that I have split dataset into train and test.Number cases for both train and test data seems perfect.  Then I use glm function using syntax below

```
fit = glm(attrition~Dept_1+Education_1+BusinessTravel_1,binomial(link="logit"),train)
```

Fit equation runs but it gets executed on entire dataset ABC with cases 1470 instead of train dataset of 1028 records.

Not able to understand what is the issue.

Comment: result of dim(train) and dim(test) are correct ?

Comment: mention "data=train"...and also show the code used to split

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
Dept_1 <- as.factor(ABC$Dept)
Education_1 <- as.factor(ABC$Education)
BusinessTravel_1 <- as.factor(ABC$BusinessTravel)
```

you're actually creating three new variables in your *global environment*, not in your original data frame `ABC`. Because of this, when you split `ABC` into training and test samples, the new variables won't be affected.

When you go to fit the model, your `glm` call

```
fit = glm(attrition~Dept_1+Education_1+BusinessTravel_1,binomial(link="logit"),train)
```

will look for the variables listed in the formula. It won't find them in the `train` dataset, but it will find them in the global environment. That's why they have the original length.

What you probably wanted is

```
ABC$Dept_1 <- as.factor(ABC$Dept)
ABC$Education_1 <- as.factor(ABC$Education)
ABC$BusinessTravel_1 <- as.factor(ABC$BusinessTravel)
```

which will create the variables in the data frame `ABC`.

Comment: While the sentiment is appreciated, StackOverflow deprecates [using comments to say "thank you"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged?lq=1); if this answer was useful you can upvote it (if you have sufficient reputation), and in any case if it answers your question satisfactorily you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.